# Unable to select a topic for Amazon Transcoder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I want to have my Amazon Transcoder post a notification to a SNS topic when some events happen, but unfortunately I'm getting an error message when I try to select the existing topic from the "Edit Pipeline" page: "Role ARN is invalid: does not start with arn"

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, apparently it seems pretty straightforward. Here's the steps I've done:

1. Selected my Pipeline
2. Click "Edit"
3. Went to "Notifications" sections and created a new topic right there (here I would expect it to have auto selected after the creation but apparently it just creates and nothing else happens..)
4. so.. I selected "Use an existing SNS topic" and selected the recently saved topic
5. Hit "Save" button
6. Got the error

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you figure this out? Im getting the same error...

Comment: Yes, I asked another user (owner of the AWS account) to do it and it worked. So, maybe try with different a user. hope that helps.

Comment: Same error here. I would really love some more information on the cause of this.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a rather weird UI bug in the AWS console.

When you edit your pipeline to set the SNS topic, the select box for the pipelines IAM role is incorrectly set to `-- Console Default Role --` (it should be `Elastic_Transcoder_Default_Role`. The entries beginning with `--` probably shouldn't be selectable at all!)

[image]

Now, when saving the form, this will cause the error.
This is not related to the selection of the Topic, as it might seem.

By changing the Role back to `Elastic_Transcoder_Default_Role` the error goes away.

Comment: @BananaNeil true :-)